# Accessing Kuberentes API using x509 certificate

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-rbac

I have created private key and certificate signed by the CA of the Kubernetes API server. I have configured the user, cluster and context in the `~/.kube/config` file. Using this context where the user has client certificate and key, what is the process to make API call to the Kubernetes API server using the client-go libraries.

Comment: Did you mean [client-go credential plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins)? If not, could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins) one can find the following excerpt:

> `k8s.io/client-go` and tools using it such as `kubectl` and `kubelet` are able to execute an external command to receive user credentials. (...)
>
> To authenticate against the API:
>
> - The user issues a  `kubectl`  command.
> - Credential plugin prompts the user for LDAP credentials, exchanges credentials with external service for a token.
> - Credential plugin returns token to client-go, which uses it as a bearer token against the API server.
> - API server uses the  [webhook token authenticator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication) to submit a  `TokenReview`  to the external service.
> - External service verifies the signature on the token and returns the user's username and groups.

See also:

- [Documentation (client go)](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go)
- [Github documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go)
- [Github documentation (auth)](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/plugin/pkg/client/auth)